# Можно ли на Windows монтировать SSD разделы в файлы, чтобы отправить в Облака разделы как файлы?

Tags: windows, файловая-система

Например раздел 100 гб значит будет файл 100 гб.
На Linux это выглядет как /dev/sda1 отправить в интернет.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-volume

Comment: Ты это ради академического интереса спрашиваешь или что-то конкретное хочешь сделать?

Comment: Эмм, образ/сжатый образ отправить в облако? Или я не понимаю задачу?